# Validating data type of all column in csv file through unix

Tags: unix

I have CSV file like this

```
dsdgh|234|@jhsjdh||jdhjdhfu|123|
#45ghf|123|laiej|||b8#hfj|
|hyrhyf|123||fhyr|@#$%|
```

and so on.

The number of column can be equals to 100. Also above file is pipe separated.

I want to check data type of each column i.e. whether a column is numeric or alphabetic or alphanumeric

and want to redirect result in txt file

please help me , to achieve this

thanks

Comment: Is number of columns in each row the same?

Comment: yes no. of columns are same in each row

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in every row number of columns is the same, you can use this script:

```
import re
import sys

input_file = open(sys.argv[1])

cols = None

for line in input_file.readlines():
    fields = line.split('|')

    if not cols:
        cols = map(lambda _: 'empty', fields)

    for i, field in enumerate(fields):
        if field == '':
            continue

        if re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', field):
            if cols[i] == 'empty':
                cols[i] = 'numeric'
            elif cols[i] == 'alphabetic':
                cols[i] = 'alphanumeric'
        elif re.match(r'^[^0-9]+$', field):
            if cols[i] == 'empty':
                cols[i] = 'alphabetic'
            if cols[i] == 'numeric':
                cols[i] = 'alphanumeric'
        else:
            cols[i] = 'alphanumeric'

print '|'.join(cols)
```

Just save it to file (`script.py` in this example), and run:

```
$ python script.py <path_to_file_with_columns>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ,but i need above script in unix

Comment: *Unix* is an operating system, not programming language. And python interpreter is available on most of posix-compatible systems, including Linux and OSX. If you want achieve that using shell script, you should include this information in your question.

Comment: yes unix is operating system ,but i don't want this solution in python , i have an another shell script i just want to add solution of above ques into that shell script